# Testing the Remix example2 contract

Tags: remix, remix-tests

I am trying to execute the remix test#2 at:
[Testing the Remix example contract#2](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unittesting_examples.html)
But I am gettig the error:

```
tests/senderTest_test.sol:33:22: DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier.
Assert.equal(getOwner(), acc0, 'owner should be acc0');
^------^
```

The sender contract is:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.7.0;
contract sender {
    address private owner;
    
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    function updateOwner(address newOwner) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "only current owner can update owner");
        owner = newOwner;
    }
    
    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }
}
//and the tester contract is:
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

// This import is automatically injected by Remix
import "remix_tests.sol"; 
import "tests/sender.sol";

import "remix_accounts.sol";

// File name has to end with '_test.sol', this file can contain more than one testSuite contracts
contract testSuite {
    //sender obj;
    address acc0;
    address acc1;
    address acc2;
    /// 'beforeAll' runs before all other tests
    /// More special functions are: 'beforeEach', 'beforeAll', 'afterEach' & 'afterAll'
    function beforeAll() public {
        // <instantiate contract>
        //Assert.equal(uint(1), uint(1), "1 should be equal to 1");
        acc0 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(0); 
        acc1 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(1);
        acc2 = TestsAccounts.getAccount(2);
        //obj = new sender();
    }
    function testInitialOwner() public {
        // account at zero index (account-0) is default account, so current owner should be acc0
        //Assert.equal(obj.getOwner(), acc0, 'owner should be acc0');
         Assert.equal(getOwner(), acc0, 'owner should be acc0');
    }
}
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `getOwner()`. It is a function of the contract sender, but you try to use it in `testSuite`. `testSuite` does not know what `getOwner()` is and where it comes from. I see that in the line before you used it correctly as `obj.getOwner()`. `obj` is of type `sender` and therefore knows how to use `getOwner()`.